Cannot config Authorization and Authentication in Solr 9.5 Standalone
I am trying out Solr 9.5 for the first time. I have installed Solr on my MacBook and can start it without any issues. The second step involves setting up Authorization and Authentication, which does not work when I follow the instructions.
The instructions for starting Solr in standalone mode (not cloud) involve creating a file named security.json, and adding the following to that file where solr.xml is /opt/solr-9.5.0/server/solr:
{
"authentication": {
    "blockUnknown": true,
    "class": "solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
    "credentials": {
        "solr": "ymoqYYPJM0dyovJW0V/Sf6jNSD6ffYVjHcoR0skpcCU=:I5HY9Lf2RFAQi1/LJaFx4w=="
    },
    "realm": "My Solr users",
    "forwardCredentials": false
},
"authorization": {
    "class": "solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "permissions": [
        {
            "name": "security-edit",
            "role": "admin"
        }
    ],
    "user-role": {
        "solr": "admin"
    }
}

}
The username is "solr," and the password is SHA256 hashed and salted using the following Python code:
import hashlib
import os
import base64

def generate_sha256_hash_and_salt(password):
    salt = os.urandom(16)
    
    hash_obj = hashlib.sha256()
    
    hash_obj.update(password.encode('utf-8') + salt)
    
    hash_base64 = base64.b64encode(hash_obj.digest()).decode('utf-8')
    salt_base64 = base64.b64encode(salt).decode('utf-8')
    return f'{hash_base64}:{salt_base64}'

def main():
    password = input("Ange lösenordet du vill hash: ")
    combined_hash_salt = generate_sha256_hash_and_salt(password)
    print("Hash och Salt kombinerat för security.json:", combined_hash_salt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


It still doesn't work, and when I restart and try, I get the following error:
Any idea what I am missing?

Finally succe. Follow the instructions provided in the Apache Solr official documentation for setting up the Basic Authentication Plugin.
https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/basic-authentication-plugin.html
Steps to Configure Authentication
Create a security.json file and populate it with the provided JSON configuration.
{
"authentication":{
   "blockUnknown": true,
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="},
   "realm":"My Solr users",
   "forwardCredentials": false
},
"authorization":{
   "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
   "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
      "role":"admin"}],
   "user-role":{"solr":"admin"}
}}

The user name is set as solr and the password is SolrRocks. The SHA-256 encrypted password is already included in the JSON snippet.
Restart Solr:
Once the security.json is properly set up, start Solr and access it via the web interface, log in using the admin credentials: username solr and password SolrRocks. Update the password upon first login.
